# making a list from values returned by a function inside a for-loop in python

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, range

The reason I decided to sign up and ask about this is because it's quite a complicated and specific question (as you can probably tell from the title of this post, lol!). Googling didn't yield anything relevant, and the only post on here that dealt with the same issue was about C, not Python.

Here's the situation:

I have a function with a for loop going through a range. The for loop calls ANOTHER function which returns a different value each time the for loop runs.
What I want to do is put all of those values returned by the function called by the for loop, into a list (the end aim is to get the minimum value in the list, which I know how to do).

I'm only a begginner programmer and I have no idea how to do this. It may be quite simple, but I can't get my head around it!

EDIT: I should have mentioned this is related to a uni assignment and I'm only allowed to use the functions and parameters defined in the specs

EDIT: @Michal, yes I should try to solve it myself and I know how to do all the things you've mentioned, but I'm stuck because of not being able to add/modify parameters to functions.

UPDATE: Problem solved! As I expected, it was something incredibly simple that I, being a bit of an idiot, didn't think of. Thanks to everyone who tried to help, I probably wouldn't have been able to figure it out without you.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "in the specs". Do you mean you're not allowed to install third-party extensions? Do you mean you can't define your own functions (since they wouldn't be "in the specs")? Do you mean they gave you a list of language features that you're allowed to use, and anything else is forbidden?

Comment: Well, you really should try and solve it yourself. The way to approach a problem like this is to decompose it: here you need to know how to call a function in Python with a given argument, how to add an item to a list, how to return a list from a function. These are all simple things which you can learn from any number of code examples available on the Web. Then try and put them together to get the final solution.

Comment: They gave starter code that already had functions - some complete, some that just had the function names and parameters defined and I had to write the rest. I'm not allowed to change the function names or parameters, or add any new ones.

Comment: Why do you have to change function names or modify parameters?

Comment: ok, so in relation to the example you gave me - the index variable of the for loop is being passed as a parameter to the function that I want to make the list from, right? another_function(i) with i being the index variable. Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: The variable `i` isn't really an index. `another_function(i)` basically calls a function called `another_function()` that takes an integer as its argument. In this case, `i` is passed as an argument to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with comprehension in one line.

```
l = [another_function(i) for i in range(lower, upper)]
```

Essentially, the expression right before the `for` keyword will get evaluated for each value of `i`. The square brackets surrounding this comprehension will save the results in a list, which you can call `min()` on it later.